# Rails - How to list parents based on latest children addtion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models- `listing` and `history` with the relationship being listing has many historys.

I want to showcase the latest listings which had history additions. The below code will retrieve them easily in the console:

```
History.last(5).uniq.each do |h|
    h.listing
end
```

But I find it difficult to implement it in the controller as a collection. The viewer is expecting a collection of `@listings`. How do I set the method in the listing controller?

I tried something like:

```
  def latest
    @listings = {}
    History.last(5).uniq.each do |h|
        @listings < h.listing
    end
  end
```

But I get the error:

> no implicit conversion of Listing into Hash

Comment: You are initializing `@listings` with a Hash instead of an array. It should be `@listings = []`, not `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do that using the `collect` method:

```
@listings = History.last(5).each.collect(&:listing)
```